# Use mfc42.dll as registration free COM?

Tags: windows, com, activex

I'm using a third party Active-X control that requires a certain version of MFC42.dll to be installed on the user's system.

I'm trying to add support for non-admin installs of my product, and having to install e.g. mfc42.dll to a system folder and register it obviously makes this impossible.

The third party Active-X is used as a registration free COM by using a manifest file, and I was wondering if it would be possible to do the same for MFC42.dll and MSVCRT.DLL and store them in the application folder? Anybody tried this?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to do this. MSVCRT and MFC42.dll are not COM objects or even win32 assemblies, and so can't be accessed using reg-free COM.

You can install mfc42.dll and msvcrt.dll app-local. The system will favour the app directory over the copies in system 32.

(see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682586(v=VS.85).aspx for full details of how DLL binding happens).

You should not need to install these DLLs except on very old OSes (pre-Win2k) because up-to-date and binary compatible copies are installed on each version of Windows, right up to Windows 7.

However, even if you do this, you would still need to synthesise a reg-free COM manifest for your ActiveX control and any COM objects it depends on (such as proxy/stubs). The SDK includes tools than can help with this, but if you don't have source to the ActiveX control, it can be non-trivial. Also note that IE cannot be caused to load reg-free COM AX controls. This is only possible in other AX hosts such as ATL or MFC.

Final note: You should also work hard to avoid taking a dependency on any component built upon mfc42 or msvcrt. These were built with a very old version of the VS toolset that lacks many important bug fixes and security updates. And the VC6 toolset that targets them (from 1998) has been unsupported for some considerable time.

Martyn